# how to where query a collectionGroup in firestore flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I need to query a collectionGroup with where clause and While doing it I stumbled on to a thing.

```
var payData = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup("payment").where("balance", isNotEqualTo: 0);
```

While executing the above code when I tried to print `payData` it prints `Instance of _JsonQuery`. How to access the data inside that variable and what's its structure.

I think the above code is incorrect.

```
var payData = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup("payment").where("balance", isNotEqualTo: 0).getDocuments();
```

After surfing I got through the above code but VSCode says it's an error in `getDocuments()`

So, What I need is to print the data that is in the variable for the query I used above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getDocuments()` was deprecated in favor of [`get()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/get.html) in version 0.14.0 of the `cloud_firestore` package ([Release notes](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore/changelog#0140)). You need to call this method on your [`Query`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/Query.html), i.e. `payData`.

The `get()` method returns a [`Future`](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await), so you can use [`then()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-async/Future/then.html) as follows:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collectionGroup("payment")
    .where("balance", isNotEqualTo: 0)
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
            print(doc["<name_of_a_field_in_the_doc>"]);
        });
    });
```

However, most of the times you will use one of the approaches shown in the FluterFire [doc](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#read-data): depending on whether you want to read the data once or listening to changes in realtime you will use a [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) or a [`StreamBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html).